# How do if statements differ from match/case statments in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, match

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) asks for a `switch/case` or `match/case` equivalent in Python. It seems since Python 3.10 we can now use `match/case` statement. I cannot see and understand the difference between `match/case` and an `if, elif` statement other than the syntactical differences!

Is there an underlying difference which makes them have different performance? or Somehow using `match/case` we can control the flow better? but How? Is there an example in which `match/case` is better than just an `if` statement?

Comment: In short, `if` requires a boolean expression to evaluate; `match` lets you perform *structural pattern matching*, which can be implemented in a less linear fashion. (Think about the difference between checking multiple cases, one after another, versus indexing a `dict` to get the correct result immediately.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/) provides an in-depth explanation for [how the new match-case statements work](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id1), [what the rationale is behind them, and provides examples where they're better than if statements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#rationale-and-goals).

In my opinion the biggest improvement over if statements is that they allow for structural pattern matching, as the PEP is named. Where if statements must be provided a truthy or falsey value, match-case statements can match against the shape/structure of an object in a concise way. Consider the following example from the PEP:

```
def make_point_3d(pt):
    match pt:
        case (x, y):
            return Point3d(x, y, 0)
        case (x, y, z):
            return Point3d(x, y, z)
        case Point2d(x, y):
            return Point3d(x, y, 0)
        case Point3d(_, _, _):
            return pt
        case _:
            raise TypeError("not a point we support")
```

It not only checks the structure of `pt`, but also unpacks the values from it and assigns them to `x`/`y`/`z` as appropriate.